# Android-jQM: MyWebViewClient::shouldOverrideUrlLoading() not working with local URI

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm using Android's `WebViewClient` to handle `<a>` clicks of my jquerymobile page.
It is working fine when my target is some full url like `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">` but if my target is local script for eg. `<a href="test.html">`, I'm not event getting the call to my `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution doing this:

```
<a href="file.php?number=<?=time();?>" ... data-ajax='false'>Link</a>
```

Hope it works for you. Cheers